# Como agregar mas tareas usando quartz.net?

Tags: c#

soy nuevo usando el framework de Quartz.net junto con c#.
Actualmente estoy creando un programa con windows form para crear respaldo de bases de datos, donde usuario puede programar tareas para que se hagan los respaldos. 
Pero me encuentro con un problema, no puedo agregar mas tareas, solo me funciona con una sola tarea a respaldar. al crear otra tarea esta no me toma el nombre de mi base de datos a seleccionar  si no la anterior.

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar o explicar como programar  mas trabajos
 Les muestro como esta la estructura de mi programa actual:

[image: Formulario principal]

**Botón que envía los parámetros:**

```
    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyGlobals.mySharedVarible1.DatabaseName = comboBox1.Text;
        MyGlobals.myShareVariable3.Departament = textBox5.Text;
        MyGlobals.mySharedVarible.TaskName = textBox1.Text;
        MyGlobals.mySharedVariable2.FileSelection = textBox4.Text;

        int Hora = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        int Minuto = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);

        Scheduler sc = new Scheduler();
        sc.Start(Hora,Minuto);

    }
```

**Mi programa que realiza el job y trigger**

```
    public void Start(int Hora, int Minuto)
    {
        string TaskName = MyGlobals.mySharedVarible.TaskName;
        string Departament= MyGlobals.myShareVariable3.Departament;

        ISchedulerFactory scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sched = scheduler.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<JobDB>()
            .WithIdentity(TaskName, Departament)
            .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
         .WithIdentity(TaskName, Departament)
           .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(Hora, Minuto))
           .WithPriority(1)
           .Build();

        sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
```

**Tarea ejecutar**

```
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server=(local); Initial Catalog=Backups; uid=""; Password=""; integrated security = true");

        string day = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss");
        string TaskName = MyGlobals.mySharedVarible1.DatabaseName + day + time;
        string query = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + MyGlobals.mySharedVarible1.DatabaseName + "] TO DISK=N'" + MyGlobals.mySharedVariable2.FileSelection + "\\" + TaskName + ".bak' WITH NOFORMAT,NOINIT";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
        conexion.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pero.. si el execute se guia por unas variables globales, que siempre son las mismas, como esperas pasarle mas de una tarea? aca hay un problema de logica.

Comment: Gracias por las recomendaciones. :D  Y si ya me había percatado sobre el uso de variables globales, alguna recomendación para poder hacerlo de otra forma?

Comment: Sin variables globales? que sentido tiene usar eso en un ambiente orientado a objetos.. usa y pasa objetos ;)

Comment: Gracias!! con tu comentario, ya pude saber cual era mi error.  Y pude solucinarlo.

Comment: Perfecto! lee los links que te pase en el primer comentario, y aprende a usar el sitio. O respondes la pregunta con una respuesta completa, o la eliminas, ya que tu problema es puntual y en realidad no le va a servir a nadie mas. Bienvenido!